# How to use Universal Image Loader to show image from Base64 content?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I have base64 string content for my list items image.
I tried using `decodeStream` method. But it won't help to load image in list view effectively(recycler view get stuck while scrolling).

`InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
 imgUserPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Then used asynchTask to load image in recycler view. Just moved the above code to AsyncTask-`doInBackground` method.

But still I'm not satisfied with this process(still scrolling get stuck).
I used `Universal Image loader` to load image throughout my app.

Is there any way to decode base64 content to get image using `Universal Image Loader`.